# Flutter - Chewie Package - Controls UI Overlap Issue

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-sliver

I am experiencing an issue with the Chewie package where the controls UI is not displaying properly.
Specifically, the time overlaps with the slider, making it difficult to read and interact with the controls and also addition options not at the corner.

ps: I am using **CustomScrollView**

```
ChewieController(
 videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
 autoInitialize: true,
 useRootNavigator: false,
 aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
)
```

[image: result]